# Jquery change value of one element to another based on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, cookies

I need to get element value of `#answer_comment` and show it inside input with id `#comment`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#answer_comment", function(e) {
        var answer = document.getElementById('answer_comment').val();
    $('#comment').val(answer);

    })
```

what is wrong?

Also if possible, how to create a cookie with the selected value?

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: Cookie creation has surely been covered here and elsewhere in enough depth to not have to ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for since it is a span you can get the value using `attr('value')`

```js
 
$("body").on("click", "#answer_comment", function(e) {
  var answer = $('#answer_comment').attr('value');
  $('#comment').val(answer);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id = "answer_comment" value="username">click here</span>
<input id="comment">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing jQuery with vanilla JS. You should pick a horse and stick to it. Pure JQ would be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on("click", "#answer_comment", function(e) {
    var answer = $('#answer_comment').text();
$('#comment').val(answer);
})
```

Comment: #comment is a input element, it's not showing the value btw

Comment: is #answer_comment an input as well?

Comment: a span doesn't have a value - you can get the text with `$('#answer_comment').text();` - see my edited answer

Comment: should I add the span inside links?

Comment: do you have some reason to? you could just have the span text as the link text